# how to get top N latest created pods inside kubernetes based on filter

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

In Kubernetes (using a filter) we can limit the output from k8s on interesting resource and I wonder whether it is possible to list top 5 latest created pods using only filter.

The current example mostly list all pods and pipe to another unix (`head` command)

```
kubectl get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | head -n 5
```

But I guess it takes quite long time to get all first from server side, then lists first 5.

Can I use special filter will make it more efficiency?

Comment: POD list is only maintained at `etcd` and typically only `kube-apiserver` could query `etcd`. POD list is not stored as sorted(on timestamp) list in the `etcd`. To sort them you need to query the entire list and sort them at client side. Which is done using `--sort-by` flag. Using `head`, `awk`, `jq` etc is trivial here.  TLDR, To sort something you need the data, which is only available at server side.

Comment: I feel it is not possible now. If someone give clear reference for this, I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several aspects which prevent you to solve this question using only `filter`:

1. `Filter` itself:

   > Field selectors are essentially resource filters. By default, no
   > selectors/filters are applied, meaning that all resources of the
   > specified type are selected. This makes the kubectl queries kubectl
   > get pods and kubectl get pods --field-selector "" equivalent.

   [Reference - Field selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/).

   And its limitations on [supported operations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/#supported-operators):

   > You can use the =, ==, and != operators with field selectors (= and ==
   > mean the same thing). This kubectl command, for example, selects all
   > Kubernetes Services that aren't in the default namespace:
   >
   > kubectl get services  --all-namespaces --field-selector
   > metadata.namespace!=default

   It can't compare value like `>` or `<` even if a number of total pods would have been available.
2. I compared requests with `--v=8` to see which exact response is performed when `kubectl get pods` is executed with different options:

   ```
   $ kubectl get pods -A --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp --v=8
   I1007 12:40:45.296727     562 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://10.186.0.2:6443/api/v1/pods?includeObject=Object
   ```

   and

   ```
   $ kubectl get pods -A --field-selector=metadata.namespace=kube-system --v=8
   I1007 12:41:42.873609    1067 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://10.186.0.2:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=metadata.namespace%3Dkube-system&limit=500
   ```

   The difference when `--field-selector` `kubectl` used is it adds `&limit=500` to the request, so it's a point where some data inconsistency can appear if using `kubectl` from terminal. While `--sort-by` get all data from `api server` to the client.
3. Using `-o jsonpath` works the same way as regular `kubectl get pods` request and has again the limit of 500 results which may lead to data inconsistency:

   ```
   $ kubectl get pods -A --v=7 -o jsonpath='{range.items[*]}{.metadata.creationTimestamp}{"\t"}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}'
   I1007 12:52:25.505109    6943 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://10.186.0.2:6443/api/v1/pods?limit=500
   ```

   Also even developers using another linux commands (`jq`, `grep`, `sort`, `|`) to work with initial results which are got from kubernetes api. See [examples of Viewing, finding resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#viewing-finding-resources).

So to confirm [@P...'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69408472/how-to-get-top-n-latest-created-pods-inside-kubernetes-based-on-filter#comment122686547_69408472), you will need to get data first to the client and only then work on it.

Comment: to me this answer is good enough, I am checking k8s event, it can give me other options.